# Python to convert special unicode characters (like ♡) to their hexadecimal literals in a string (like 0x2661)

Tags: python, string, bash, unicode, tweepy

I'm writing a program that pulls screen names and tweets from twitter into a txt file. Some screen names contain special unicode characters like ♡. In my Bash terminal these characters show up as an empty box. My sql fails when I try to insert this character and tells me it contains an untranslatable character. Is there a way to convert only special characters in python to their hexadecimal form? I would also be happy just replacing these special characters with

Ideally "screenName♡" would convert to "screenName0x2661" or just replace special characters to something like "screenName#REPLACE#"

Comment: try url encode methods... ?

Comment: When there are 800 special characters for each ordinary character, perhaps there's a problem with this classification.

Comment: In shell, you can pipe through `iconv -t US-ASCII --unicode-subst="0x%x"` if you have libiconv installed. I'm sure you can do this within python as well if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `encode` method, explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html). From the docs:

> Another important method is .encode([encoding], [errors='strict']),
>   which returns an 8-bit string version of the Unicode string, encoded
>   in the requested encoding. The errors parameter is the same as the
>   parameter of the unicode() constructor, with one additional
>   possibility; as well as ‘strict’, ‘ignore’, and ‘replace’, you can
>   also pass ‘xmlcharrefreplace’ which uses XML’s character references.
>   The following example shows the different results:

```
>>> u = unichr(40960) + u'abcd' + unichr(1972)
>>> u.encode('utf-8') '\xea\x80\x80abcd\xde\xb4'
>>> u.encode('ascii')                        Traceback (most recent call last):
    ... UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ua000' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'ignore') 'abcd'
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'replace') '?abcd?'
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace') '&#40960;abcd&#1972;'
```

Comment: I was missing the u in front of my quotes. Having it as u'screenName♡' instead of just 'screenName♡' makes the encoding work. Thanks!